# Laravel5 How to get data from HTTP PUT request?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have HTTP PUT API but cannot retrieve from the request. Input::all() returns empty. Can you share how to do it? I confirmed that $request had form-data.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    Log::info(Input::all()); // empty
    Log::info($id); // 1001
    Log::info($request);
}

$request -> 

local.INFO: PUT /v1/shops/1001 HTTP/1.1
.
.
.
------WebKitFormBoundary2B26VoCplFAB8W36
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="item_id"

9001
------WebKitFormBoundary2B26VoCplFAB8W36
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

tokyo
```

Route.php

```
<?php
Route::resource('v1/shops', 'ShopController');
?>
```

Detail

```
$request -> 
local.INFO: PUT /v1/shops/1001 HTTP/1.1
Accept:          */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: ja,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6
Cache-Control:   no-cache
Connection:      keep-alive
Content-Length:  332
Content-Type:    multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryAchDYDABHI1GDUeu
Cookie:          XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Host:            XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Origin:          chrome-extension://aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo
Postman-Token:   434976e3-3476-3dcd-3689-7048d523dd20
User-Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36

------WebKitFormBoundary2B26VoCplFAB8W36
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="item_id"

9001
------WebKitFormBoundary2B26VoCplFAB8W36
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

tokyo
```

Comment: Is the route a PUT route, or is it in a resource?

Comment: Which is your Content-Type?

Comment: resource. Route::resource('v1/shops', 'ShopController');

Comment: The request header has Content-Type application/json

Comment: Does dd($request) shows input info or it's empty?

Comment: dd($request) is empty

Comment: Can you post your `routes.php`.

Comment: Updated. Only one setting . <?php
Route::resource('v1/shops', 'ShopController');
?>

Comment: and @zono, the view in which you have your form, can you post it as well.

Comment: No I don't have. Just I used http simulator. The tool is poster. Chrome extension . Something wrong about using it...? I'll check it

Comment: In that case, it might be something with the simulator. Are you sure that form data can be sent as a _real_ request with the simulator?

Comment: Thanks I'm checking it now. I edited my question. "Content-Type:    multipart/form-data;" is right sorry.

Comment: Thanks guys. I fixed it and posted the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I should have selected "x-xxx-form-urlencoded". not "form-data"

[image]

I got this form data and could retrieve by Input::all()

```
user_id=1&address=2&tag=3
```

This issue a was clue. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/8